# Dot-product of log-likelihood gradients ("scores")

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, distance

Given two probability densities $p(x)$ and $p(y)$, define the dot-product of their log-likelihood gradients, also sometimes known as "scores", $\langle \nabla_x \log p(x), \nabla_y \log p(y) \rangle $. I was wondering if this pops up in a specific definition of a distance measure between distributions, is there a connection? Would appreciate some pointers :)